# Android Message in loop

Tags: android, service, message-passing, messenger

I need to send data from a class to the main UI Activity and i am trying to do this with message passing.

Unfortunately my handler didn't receive the message sent inside a loop. I show you my code so far:

In the UI Activity

```
private final Handler mIncomingHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
           case MESSAGE_READ:
               tedit.setText("Received " + msg.arg1);
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
};

private final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(mIncomingHandler);

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mTransferServiceBound = true;
        Message msg = Message.obtain(null, TransferService.MSG_REG_CLIENT);
        msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
        mTransferService = new Messenger(service);
        try {
            mTransferService.send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to register client");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mTransferService = null;
        mTransferServiceBound = false;
    }

};
```

In the service

```
private class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MSG_REG_CLIENT:
            Log.d(TAG, "Activity client registered");
            mClient = msg.replyTo;
            waitCommunication();
            break;
        case MSG_UNREG_CLIENT:
            mClient = null;
            stopSelf();
            break;
        default:
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());


private void waitCommunication() {
       int i = 0;
       while(true) {
         try {
       mClient.send(Message.obtain(null, MainActivity.Message_READ, i++, -1));
      } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to send Message", e);
      }
       }
    }
```

When i try to send the message without the while(true) it works fine, but like i described above i simply didn't receive any message on the handler.

Can someone help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the service is running on the UI thread. Thus if you have an endless loop running, the Activity will never get any CPU time to respond to the message.

Instead of doing while (true) {...}, allocate a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). You can use its various post methods to do things repeatedly at timed intervals, or even as fast as possible, without totally blocking all other activity on the UI thread.